# Gecko usage in C# (geckofx)

Tags: c#, geckofx

There are some things that I didn't find how to do using geckofx:

1. Get the URL of a clicked link.
2. Display print preview window.

Does this functionality exist in geckofx? If not, what's the best way
to achieve it in a C# project that uses GeckoWebBrowser to display html pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get url of clicked link you can use:

```
    void domClicked(object sender, GeckoDomMouseEventArgs e)
    {
     if(geckoWebBrowser1.StatusText.StartsWith("http"))
     {
      MessageBox.Show(geckoWebBrowser1.StatusText);//forward status text string somewhere
     }
    }
```

To show print dialog box you can use:

```
    geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:print()");
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnNaviagted` event should give you the link, and look for the print interfaces `nsIPrintingPromptService::ShowPrintDialog` in Geckofx.

Answer (score 1):

```
geckoWebBrowser.url
```

That will give you the url at any point I believe where geckoWebBrowser is the name of the control, however as pointed out you'll be able to get it from the document completed and navigated events using e.url .

Answer (score 0):

For printing, see [this forum thread.](http://geckofx.org/viewtopic.php?id=168&p=1) Make sure to read it all before starting. Essentially you'll have to patch and recompile GeckoFX.